# Access external libraries (JARs) from another JAR in JBOSS/Wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I've written a custom jar which should be added to a Keycloak's deployment folder (Keycloak runs on a JBOSS/Wildfly server). The problem I'm facing is that after deployment, no external jar seems to be reachable. This looks like is mnore related to JBOSS/Wildfly class/module loading mechanism, than Keycloak itself.

I'm receiving following error from the console when the code hits an external class:

```
  11:21:56,095 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (default task-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport in Module 
  "deployment.spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/ws/client/core/support/WebServiceGatewaySupport 
  (Module "deployment.spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

1 - I've followed the approach described here : [Deploy JAR as a module on JBoss 7.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746031/deploy-jar-as-a-module-on-jboss-7-1-1)

2 - the libraries load correctly as seen on the console:

```
11:19:21,883 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/auth' for server 'default-server'
11:19:22,021 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "spring-xml-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar" (runtime-name : "spring-xml-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar")
11:19:22,021 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "keycloak-server.war" (runtime-name : "keycloak-server.war")
11:19:22,021 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar" (runtime-name : "spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar")
11:19:22,022 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "maven-jaxb23-plugin-0.14.0.jar" (runtime-name : "maven-jaxb23-plugin-0.14.0.jar")
11:19:22,023 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "maven-jaxb2-plugin-core-0.14.0.jar" (runtime-name : "maven-jaxb2-plugin-core-0.14.0.jar")
11:19:22,023 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "maven-jaxb2-plugin-0.14.0.jar" (runtime-name : "maven-jaxb2-plugin-0.14.0.jar")
11:19:22,023 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "customIsaacAuthenticatorKeycloakSPI-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" (runtime-name : "customIsaacAuthenticatorKeycloakSPI-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")
```

3- My MANIFEST.MF looks like this (and is also correctly loading after checking all dependencies):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: [ - me :) -]
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_131
Dependencies: deployment.spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar, deployment.
 spring-xml-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar, deployment.maven-jaxb2-plugin-0.14.0.ja
 r, deployment.maven-jaxb2-plugin-core-0.14.0.jar, deployment.maven-ja
 xb23-plugin-0.14.0.jar
```

Nevertheless the problem recongnizing an external class from JBOSS/WILDFLY (where Keycloak is deployed) remains. Can somebody please help me pointing out a possible approach as to how can I make the external library jar be visible from my SPI jar?

Thanks is advance!